# it's ternary operator issue or BigDecimal issue?

Tags: java

I want to get the price of `1190`...

- code

```java
public void test() {
        String s = "usdt_krw";
        BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.valueOf(1190.00000000);
        String[] split = s.split("_");

        System.out.println(split[0]);
        System.out.println(b.intValue());

        System.out.println(
                "first => " + Tests.builder()
                        .price(String.valueOf(
                                split[0].equals("usdt")
                                ? b.intValue()
                                : b.doubleValue()))
                        .build());

        System.out.println(
                "second => " + Tests.builder()
                .price(split[0].equals("usdt")
                        ? String.valueOf(b.intValue())
                        : String.valueOf(b.doubleValue()))
                .build());
}
```

- result

```
usdt
1190
first => Tests(accountId=null, amount=null, price=1190.0, symbol=null, type=null)
second => Tests(accountId=null, amount=null, price=1190, symbol=null, type=null)
```

I think the first and second results should be the same.

Comment: You need to explain more and describe what you are trying to do.  The output does not reflect the code you have shown.  If you are doing any testing you need to explain that too.

Comment: You only have 3 `println` statements, so how come you get 4 lines of output? --- Unable to reproduce!

Comment: I'm sorry, I've corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `true ? 123 : 4.56` will yield a `double` 123.0, a *balancing cast*, 123 is cast to double.
- `true ? "123" : "4.56" will yield a`String` "123".